# Python Removing non-alphabetical characters with exceptions

Tags: python

I am having a hard time doing Data Analysis on a large text that has lots of non-alphabetical chars. I tried using

```py
string = filter(str.isalnum, string)
```

but I also have `"@"` in my text that I want to keep. How do I make an exception for a character like `"@"` ?

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to use regular expressions:

```
string = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9@]", "", string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'[^\w\s\d@]', '', string)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\s\d@]', '', 'This is @ string 123 *$^%')
This is @ string 123
```

Comment: You don't need `|` for "or" inside a character class (square brackets).

Comment: The regex pattern should use a [**raw string**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html?highlight=regex#the-backslash-plague): `r"[^\w\s\d@]"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `lambda` function to specify your allowed characters. But also note that [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns a `<filter object>` which is an iterator over the returned values. So you will have to stich it back to a string:

```py
string = "?filter_@->me3!"

extra_chars = "@!"

filtered_object = filter(lambda c: c.isalnum() or c in extra_chars, string)

string = "".join(filtered_object)

print(string)
```

Gives:

```py
filter@me3!
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a function that returns `True` or `False` if an input character is valid.

```py
import string

valid_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '@'

def is_valid_character(character):
    return character in valid_characters

# Instead of using `filter`, we `join` all characters in the input string
# if `is_valid_character` is `True`.
def get_valid_characters(string):
    return "".join(char for char in string if is_valid_character(char))
```

Some example output:

```py
>>> print(valid_characters)
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@

>>> get_valid_characters("!Hello_#world?")
'Helloworld'

>>> get_valid_characters("user@example")
'user@example'
```

A simpler way to write it would be using regex. This will accomplish the same thing:

```py
import re

def get_valid_characters(string):
    return re.sub(r"[^\w\d@]", "", string)
```